# creation of parent account when child get some condition trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

hi helpies i am new here  i stuck over here please help me

i am writing trigger over contact whenever new contact created and some condition met  a new parent account should be created . i have done with creation of account but how to make it parent here i stuck

code is below..

```
trigger accountcreatecon on Contact (after insert) {

    List<Account> list_acc = new List<Account>(); 
    Map<id, Account> con_acc_map = new Map<id, Account>();
            set <id> idset=new set <id>();
    for(contact c :trigger.new){
        if(c.lastname.startswith('a') && (c.email.endswith('gmail.com') ||c.email.endswith('yahoo.com')  ) && (c.phone.startswith('888') || c.phone.startswith('999'))){

        Account a = new Account(Name=c.lastname);
        idset.add(a.id);
        list_acc.add(a);
        }
    }
    insert list_acc;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trigger triggertest on Contact (before insert) {

List list_acc = new List();

Map con_acc_map = new Map();

set  idset = new set ();

for(contact c : trigger.new){

if( (c.lastname.startswith('a') || c.lastname.startswith('A') )&&
           (c.email.endswith('gmail.com') || c.email.endswith('yahoo.com')  )
           && (c.phone.startswith('888') || c.phone.startswith('999')))
        {
            list_acc.add(new Account(Name = c.LastNAme)) ;
        }
    }

if(list_acc.size() > 0){

insert list_acc;
    }

for(Account a : list_acc ){

con_acc_map.put(a.name,a.id)  ;
    }

for(Contact c1 : Trigger.New){

c1.accountid=con_acc_map.get(c1.lastname);
    }

}

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement here is to create a new Account and associate it to the contact record.. A concerns:

1. Try creating the trigger Before Insert as it will eliminate the need of using a DML statement.

> ```
> trigger triggertest on Contact (before insert) {
>
>     List<Account> list_acc = new List<Account>(); 
>     Map<id, Account> con_acc_map = new Map<id, Account>();
>     set <id> idset = new set <id>();
>     for(contact c : trigger.new){
>         if( (c.lastname.startswith('a') || c.lastname.startswith('A') )&&  
>            (c.email.endswith('gmail.com') || c.email.endswith('yahoo.com')  )   
>            && (c.phone.startswith('888') || c.phone.startswith('999')))
>         {
>             list_acc.add(new Account(Name = c.LastNAme)) ;          
>         }                
>     }
>
>     if(!list_acc.isEmpty()){
>         insert list_acc;
>         for(Contact c1 : Trigger.New){
>             for(Account a : list_acc ){
>                 idset.add(a.id);
>                 c1.AccountId = a.Id; 
>             }
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

Or you can go with following compact code :

```
trigger triggertest on Contact (before insert) {

    set <id> idset = new set <id>();
    for(contact c : trigger.new){
        if( (c.lastname.startswith('a') || c.lastname.startswith('A') ))
        {
            Account a = new Account(Name = c.LastNAme) ;    
            insert a;
            c.AccountId = a.Id; 
            idset.add(a.id);
        } 

    }           
}
```

Comment: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Account Name]: [Account Name]: Trigger.accountcreatecon: line 17, column 1(on insert operation) insted of a i used list_acc  bt the scope of list_acc is limited inside for loop i think it shold nt work in last line so for that i was using set<id> to store and retrieve later

Comment: @SunilChandel Try using the edited code, i tested the code, working fine without errors but you need to work over the conditions in IF statement

Comment: thanks mam its working . only i dont want was for loop inside for loop. thats still exist

Comment: That is why the compact code is posted. i wanted to avoid too much of loops... so i reduced to code by putting the DML inside the loop.

Comment: If we put the DML outside the loop, we need to implement it ending up with unnecessary loops

Comment: so dml inside loop is also not a proper way by the way atleast its working . thanks for help

Comment: It`s not the best practice but yet either you write DML inside loop or you write excess for loops